# How to convert a centralize dependencies array in groovy to kotlin?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, kotlin, dependencies

In groovy script I could assign a list of dependencies in an array as "implementation libraries.frameworkLibs", does similar approach exists in kotlin?

The goal is to have a list of dependencies in an array, so that each list can be individually assigned in the subprojects.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

/* 1. centerilize dependencies for all projects */
ext.libraries = [
    frameworkLibs: [
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
        'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.0.1',
        'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    ],
    testLibs: [
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test',
        'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
    ],
    sqlLibs: [
        'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    ]
]

allprojects {
    group = 'com.example'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        /* 2. establish dependencies */
        implementation libraries.frameworkLibs
        runtimeOnly libraries.sqlLibs
        testImplementation libraries.testLibs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your map of dependencies to:

```
val libraries by extra {
    mapOf(
            "frameworkLibs" to listOf(
                    "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis",
                    "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
                    "org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.0.1",
                    "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka"
            )
    )
}
```

And then in your dependencies block it will need to be:

```
    libraries["frameworkLibs"]?.forEach { s -> implementation(s) }
```

You could add an extension method to Project as part of a buildSrc script to hide this `forEach` to get the dependencies working...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable to store the dependencies, then in the `allprojects` or `subprojects` block you can refer to that array. For example you could define a class which stores your different types of dependencies (each as an array of strings, for example), create an instance of that class and populate it, store a reference to that in  variable, then use that variable's value to assign the dependencies, as shown below:

```
class Libraries(val frameworkLibs: Array<String>, val testLibs: Array<String>, val sqlLibs: Array<String>)

val libraries = Libraries(
    arrayOf(
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
        "org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.0.1",
        "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka"
    ),
    arrayOf(
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test",
        "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test"
    ),
    arrayOf("org.postgresql:postgresql")
)

allprojects {
    dependencies {
        libraries.frameworkLibs.forEach { implementation(it) }
        libraries.sqlLibs.forEach { runtimeOnly(it) }
        libraries.testLibs.forEach { testImplementation(it) }
```

I can't seem to find a way to pass the array of dependencies into methods such as `implementation` or `runtimeOnly`, so instead I'm looping round them and adding each dependency individually. If there is a way to pass the array in in one line, hopefully someone else can tell us how.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks tim_yates and Yoni Gibbs.  Following implementation solved my problem.

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.4.RELEASE"
    java

    // this plugin is required for Kotlin
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

val libraries by extra {
    mapOf(
        "frameworkLibs" to listOf(
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
            "org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.0.1",
            "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka"
        ),
        "testLibs" to listOf(
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test",
            "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test"
        ),
        "sqlLibs" to listOf(
            "org.postgresql:postgresql"
        ),
        "testLibs" to listOf(
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test",
            "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test"
        )
    )
}

allprojects {
    group = "com.example"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

    dependencies {
        libraries["frameworkLibs"]?.forEach { s -> implementation(s) }
        libraries["testLibs"]?.forEach { s -> implementation(s) }
        libraries["sqlLibs"]?.forEach { s -> runtimeOnly(s) }
        libraries["testLibs"]?.forEach { s -> testImplementation(s) }
    }
}
```